# Best practise populate Bootstrap HTML form SELECT dropdown with values from database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

UPDATE:

I have made some changes and updated the code.

It works better now and when loading the form, the value from the database is automatically shown in the form field, this is done by adding "selected" to the OPTION tag.

However, I still have a bug somewhere:

When selecting a new value it is stored correctly in the DB and displayed in the field when submitting the form, but only if I choose a value below the previous value in the drop-down. If a value above the previous value is selected, the new value is stored in DB but the old value is still displayed in the form field.

When debugging the HTML output I can see that for some reason both the old value and the new value is listed as "selected" options. I use the "if...elseif....else" Statement and believed this was correct but I do not understand why I get two options "selected" after submit. Have I understood the usage of IF statement wrong?

A part of the HTML output:

```
<option value="MDV">Maldives</option>
<option value="MLI" selected>Mali</option>
<option value="MLT" selected>Malta</option>
<option value="MHL">Marshall Islands</option>
```

---

ORGINAL QUESTION:

I have seen many examples of methods for populating a drop-down in an html form with the use of PHP and values from a MySQL database. I have chosen one that for me looks efficient and easy to understand.

However my problem is that the rest of my form pre-populates form fields with data from the database and I am struggling to find out how I can do the same with my SELECT tag. I would like to ask what is best practice for this task? Is my code correct from a general point of view when populating a drop-down or shall I use a third party script like "Selectize" or "bootstrap-select" to accomplish this?

Worth mentioning is that I am aiming for a solution where if the value do not already exist, the user can suggest their own value and add it to the DB. Any variant of type-ahead would also be preferred for those drop-downs containing a large number of options. But for now I have only been focused on learning the basics.

My existing code, which is working for providing the drop-down with the correct values and store the selected value in the DB. I have failed to show the chosen value after pressing submit and instead the first value in the array is shown ad default value for the drop-down.

PHP Code:

```
//Get countries
$sth = $db->prepare ("SELECT iso3, short_name FROM country ORDER BY short_name ASC");
$sth->execute();
$CountryList = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="country">Country</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
  <?php 
  foreach ($CountryList as $row) {
      if ($row['iso3'] == $_POST['country']) {
        echo "<option value={$row['iso3']} selected>";
        } elseif ($row['iso3'] == $country) {
            echo "<option value={$row['iso3']} selected>";
            } else {
            echo "<option value={$row['iso3']}>";
            }
        echo $row['short_name'];
        echo '</option>';
        }
  ?>
  </select>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just check if $row['short_name'] is equal to the post var, then add a "selected" attribute to the option tag.

Comment: I tried to do this but am still doing something wrong, please see the updated question with new code and let me know if you have more suggestions. 

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be ending your foreach loop too early, you also need to specify a value for your option, like so:

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="country">Country</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
   <?php foreach ($CountryList as $row): ?>
   <option value="<?=$row["short_name"]?>">
    <?=$row["short_name"]?>
   </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Another thing to mention is that you are missing a greater than sign on your opening div

Comment: I changed my code and adapted your recommendation, however I have a bug when selecting a new value. Please see the updated question with new code and let me know if you have more suggestions. Thank you for your time.